# NSLCD only connects to LDAP server in debug mode

Tags: centos, ldap

Hey guys I searched a bit on stackexchange but could find help for my problem.

I'm trying to integrating LDAP authentication on a centos 7 client, but I can't get it working, and I can't find out why. Here's some info

I made a clear install of centos 7

went into `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig` and changed

```
FORCELEGACY=no
```

to

```
FORCELEGACY=yes
```

So authconfig don't use SSSD because i won't be using TSL/SSL for my connection, which as I understand it is a requirement for using SSSD.

then I ran `authconfig-tui` to populate `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`

```
SASL_NOCANON    on
URI ldap://172.16.0.5:390
BASE dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
```

now I went in `/etc/nslcd.confg` and populated it manually

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap

uri ldap://172.16.0.5:390

ldap_version 3

base dc=mosek,dc=zentyal

binddn cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
bindpw secret

scope sub
base   group  ou=Groups,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
base   passwd ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
base   shadow ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal

ssl no
```

I ran authconfig-tui again to be sure that nslcd picked up the new configs

I checked my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to see if it was configured correctly:

```
passwd:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
group:      files ldap

hosts:      files dns

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files

netgroup:   files ldap

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files ldap
aliases:    files nisplus
```

then I tried to log in, but it wouldn't let me. I therefore checked `/var/log/messeges` and found:

```
Nov 27 12:48:01 localhost systemd: Starting Naming services LDAP client daemon....
Nov 27 12:48:01 localhost systemd: PID file /var/run/nslcd/nslcd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Nov 27 12:48:01 localhost nslcd[10991]: version 0.8.13 starting
Nov 27 12:48:01 localhost nslcd[10991]: accepting connections
Nov 27 12:48:01 localhost systemd: Started Naming services LDAP client daemon..
Nov 27 12:49:10 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:10 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:11 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:11 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:12 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:12 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:13 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:13 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:14 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:14 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:15 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:15 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:16 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:16 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:17 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:17 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:18 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:18 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
Nov 27 12:49:19 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:49:19 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8b4567] <passwd(all)> no available LDAP server found: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:52:23 localhost nslcd[10991]: [7b23c6] <passwd="tomas"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:52:23 localhost nslcd[10991]: [7b23c6] <passwd="tomas"> no available LDAP server found: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:52:26 localhost nslcd[10991]: [3c9869] <passwd="tomas"> no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:52:26 localhost nslcd[10991]: [334873] <passwd="tomas"> no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:52:26 localhost nslcd[10991]: [b0dc51] <passwd="tomas"> no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:53:59 localhost nslcd[10991]: [495cff] <passwd="tomas"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.16.0.5:390: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:53:59 localhost nslcd[10991]: [495cff] <passwd="tomas"> no available LDAP server found: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:54:02 localhost nslcd[10991]: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:54:02 localhost nslcd[10991]: [5558ec] <passwd="tomas"> no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Transport endpoint is not connected
Nov 27 12:54:02 localhost nslcd[10991]: [8e1f29] <passwd="tomas"> no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

my `/var/log/secure` looks like this:

```
Nov 27 12:37:34 localhost sshd[10926]: Invalid user tomas from 172.16.0.179
Nov 27 12:37:34 localhost sshd[10926]: input_userauth_request: invalid user tomas [preauth]
Nov 27 12:37:39 localhost sshd[10926]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov 27 12:37:39 localhost sshd[10926]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=harbinger.mosek.zentyal
Nov 27 12:37:41 localhost sshd[10926]: Failed password for invalid user tomas from 172.16.0.179 port 37863 ssh2
Nov 27 12:37:44 localhost sshd[10926]: Connection closed by 172.16.0.179 [preauth]
Nov 27 12:52:23 localhost sshd[11004]: Invalid user tomas from 172.16.0.179
Nov 27 12:52:23 localhost sshd[11004]: input_userauth_request: invalid user tomas [preauth]
Nov 27 12:52:26 localhost sshd[11004]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov 27 12:52:26 localhost sshd[11004]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=harbinger.mosek.zentyal
Nov 27 12:52:28 localhost sshd[11004]: Failed password for invalid user tomas from 172.16.0.179 port 38262 ssh2
Nov 27 12:52:30 localhost sshd[11004]: Connection closed by 172.16.0.179 [preauth]
Nov 27 12:53:59 localhost sshd[11014]: Invalid user tomas from 172.16.0.179
Nov 27 12:53:59 localhost sshd[11014]: input_userauth_request: invalid user tomas [preauth]
Nov 27 12:54:02 localhost sshd[11014]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov 27 12:54:02 localhost sshd[11014]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=harbinger.mosek.zentyal
Nov 27 12:54:04 localhost sshd[11014]: Failed password for invalid user tomas from 172.16.0.179 port 38274 ssh2
Nov 27 12:54:06 localhost sshd[11014]: Connection closed by 172.16.0.179 [preauth]
Nov 27 13:18:38 localhost unix_chkpwd[11120]: check pass; user unknown
Nov 27 13:18:38 localhost unix_chkpwd[11120]: password check failed for user (tomas)
Nov 27 13:18:38 localhost sshd[11118]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=harbinger.mosek.zentyal  user=tomas
Nov 27 13:18:38 localhost unix_chkpwd[11121]: could not obtain user info (tomas)
Nov 27 13:18:38 localhost sshd[11118]: Failed password for tomas from 172.16.0.179 port 38466 ssh2
Nov 27 13:18:38 localhost sshd[11118]: fatal: Access denied for user tomas by PAM account configuration [preauth]
Nov 27 13:22:09 localhost unix_chkpwd[11143]: check pass; user unknown
Nov 27 13:22:09 localhost unix_chkpwd[11143]: password check failed for user (tomas)
Nov 27 13:22:09 localhost sshd[11141]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=harbinger.mosek.zentyal  user=tomas
Nov 27 13:22:09 localhost unix_chkpwd[11144]: could not obtain user info (tomas)
Nov 27 13:22:09 localhost sshd[11141]: Failed password for tomas from 172.16.0.179 port 38501 ssh2
Nov 27 13:22:09 localhost sshd[11141]: fatal: Access denied for user tomas by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

And that I found really wierd because I have an Ubuntu client which connects just fine, to that address: 172.16.0.5:390

I tried running `nslcd` in debug mode, I tried logging in again, I just went crazy, when i tried logging in:

```
$ ssh tomas@centosy
tomas@centosy's password: 
Connection closed by 172.16.0.188
```

---

```
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> (re)loading /etc/nsswitch.conf
nslcd: [8b4567] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Groups,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(|(memberUid=tomas)(member=uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal)))")
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=__USERS__,ou=Groups,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=Domain Admins,ou=Groups,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=staff,ou=Groups,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): cn=admins,ou=Groups,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [7b23c6] <group/member="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (4 total)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [b0dc51] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [b0dc51] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [b0dc51] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [495cff] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG:     nslcd_pam_authc("tomas","sshd","***")
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(objectClass=*)")
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: bind successful
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [495cff] <authc="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [e8944a] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [e8944a] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [5558ec] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [5558ec] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [5558ec] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [5558ec] <passwd="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [8e1f29] DEBUG: connection from pid=11118 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG:     nslcd_pam_authz("tomas","sshd","","harbinger.mosek.zentyal","ssh")
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [8e1f29] <authz="tomas"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
```

it like nslcd only can contact the ldap server, in debug-mode. When I try starting nslcd it fails becuase it can't contact the server, but as you can see, when it is in debug-mode it connects just fine.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check if pam_ldap is properly reading /etc/openldap/ldap.conf instead of /etc/pam_ldap.conf which is (if I recall correctly) default?

Comment: How do I check that exactly? sorry I'm a bit green in this field

Comment: easiest way I can think of is to symlink /etc/openldap/ldap.conf to /etc/pam_ldap.conf and retry it. pam debugging is a pain; I'd suggest turning on debug=1 in pam.d/* but pam_ldap.so ignores it.

Comment: well I symlinked ldap.conf to /etc/pam_ldap.conf and rebooted, but it changed nothing, sadly.

Comment: If you aren't set on doing it with `nslcd`, try using `sssd`.

Comment: if so could you show me how to configure `sssd` then?

Comment: @Tomas: thats what the [manual](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Documentation) is for...

Comment: SSSD doesn't do the trick either

Comment: As the other commenters suggested, provide logs to illustrate what exactly is "not working".

Comment: Can you paste your /etc/nsswitch.conf? It seems that pam_ldap.so isn't even being called. FYI sssd does not officially support cleartext authentication.

Comment: I posted my nsswitch

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using TLS/SSL over unencrypted binds. Sniffing passwords and account data over a plain connection is just too easy. Plus, this might be related: http://serverfault.com/questions/627809/ssh-login-with-ldap-users-over-nslcd-works-after-restarting-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem

I just went in and disabled selinux by going into `/etc/selinux/config` and set
`SELINUX=disabled`

I did a quick reboot, and I could log in, no problem

Comment: http://stopdisablingselinux.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is how we did it on our boxes, so be warned, it might not apply to your setup.

A few caveats:

- Our server has a valid CA-signed certificate, be sure to modify `ldap_tls_cacert` if yours has a self-signed certificate (which is bad (tm) anyway).
- We use LDAP to provide sudo rules, to leave that out if you don't want it.
- You might want to set `ldap_group_search_base` and `ldap_search_base` too, to limit `sssd`'s search to valid users/groups only. Same goes for `ldap_sudo_search_base`.
- Be sure to set `ldap_user_member_of` to match your directory server's group membership attribute on the user side. (It's `groupmembership` for eDirectory)
- Be sure to set `ldap_access_filter` to restrict access to your system(s). Otherwise all valid users may log on to your box.
- Check your user's LDAP data before looking for errors on the `sssd` or `PAM` side of the login process.
- Make sure that `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`'s permissions are set `0600`.

In our case, my user has these attributes set for LDAP Login:

```
objectClass: posixAccount
groupMembership: cn=group1,...
groupMembership: cn=group2,...
uid: fuero
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 19999
homeDirectory: /home/fuero
```

`/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

```
[domain/default]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
access_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
sudo_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://your.ldap-server.tld:636
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=your-bind-user
ldap_default_authtok_type = obfuscated_password
ldap_default_authtok = your_password_hash
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
cache_credentials = false
enumerate = false

[sssd]
services = nss, pam, ssh, sudo
config_file_version = 2
domains = default

[nss]

[pam]

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]
```

Setup `nsswitch.conf` to use `sssd`:

```
# grep sss /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
services:   files sss
netgroup:   files sss
sudoers: files sss
```

Verify:

```
# id fuero
uid=100000(fuero) gid=19999(users) groups=20000(group1),20000(group2)
```

Set up PAM `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
**auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass**
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
**account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so**
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
**session optional        pam_sss.so
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so        umask=0077**
```

Comment: I added my own non-working sssd.conf to the question

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be systemd. Try running nslcd yourself will see it working.

When you start nslcd using systemctl, it spawns a new process when you try to query nslcd. In messages I see:

```
Dec  3 19:53:33 myhostname nslcd[2227]: [8b4567] <passwd="myuser"> problem closing server socket (ignored): Bad file descriptor
Dec  3 19:53:33 myhostname nslcd[2227]: [8b4567] <passwd="myuser"> version 0.8.13 bailing out
```

I don't understand the root cause yet, but systemctl has something to do with it.

I have another system that set up before this one and is working, and systemctl is systemd-208-11.el7_0.2.x86_64, while the new one that is NOT working is systemd-208-11.el7_0.4.x86_64.

Comment: stupid question, but how would I run nslcd myself? it isn't located in init.d. EDIT: found it, but it didn't change anything staring it on my own